# How to insert new record with sequence on postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table 'new_table' with sequence id as primary key.
how can I insert new records to it with data from other table. I tried:

```
insert into new_table ( 
(select (select NEXTVAL('my_sequence')),a,b,c from old_table)
);
```

but got

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint DETAIL:  Key (id)=(...)
>   already exists.

Comment: First, check to see what you are actually getting back from the sequence object ( run this part :  select NEXTVAL('my_sequence').
Your Sequence and your table my have gotten out of sequence resulting in a conflict.

Comment: Second, isolate your sequence selection its own selection statement, putting it into a variable, then using that variable within the insert statement.  It will be easier for debugging, and for future maintenance.

Comment: TNX Maybe you can write an example ?

Comment: Just omit the sequence :`insert into new_table ( a, b, c) select a,b,c from old_table;`

Answer (score 0):

1. just list columns skipping the one with sequence, smth like:

   `insert into new_table (a,b,c) select a,b,c from old_table;`

If default value is set to get nextval, you don't have to do it manually.

2. check if your sequence is not behind the max(id) value. smth like:

`select max(id) from new_table`

if it is, restart sequence with new cellar, smth like:

`alter sequence my_sequence restart with 1999;` or what your maximum is

Comment: You can combine the check the setting of the new value using `select setval('my_sequence', (select max(id) from new_table))`

Comment: should I add this to answer? I thought to put it as simple as possible